# how to write mod_rewrite rules just for php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rule for a directory of my site.

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(css|font|img|js)/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.])$ $1/$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\_]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

but I cant understand why it is not working well.

1- I want users have direct access to these directories `css|font|img|js` 
(just for files, not directory lists. rewrite directory list to `403.php`)

2- I want users have direct access to `*.js|*.css` files in view directory.
(not other file. rewrite other to `403.php`)

3- I want to rewrite every other urls to `index.php?url=$1`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your pattern: `/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.])$` means a slash, followed by exactly one character of a letter, number slash or a dot, then the end. I'm guessing you want something like:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(css|font|img|js)/ - [L,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css)$
RewriteRule ^view/ - [L,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule !^(css|font|img|js)/ /403.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^view/ /403.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `RewriteCond`?

You could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|font|img|js)/
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\_]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This way you do a *noop* rewrite for files inside the *css*, *font*, *img* and *js* directories and do the `index.php` rewrite for all other URLs.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ target_file.php?=url$1 [L,NC]

#allow access to file js and css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC]
```

When use [L, NC] don't redirect to other page:

If you access localhost/page.php this don't redirect to target_file.php?url=/page.php

but continue in same url and appears the file target_file.php